# mysql query different,performance is different

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query What is the difference?
id is the primary key

```
1, select id from tbl_xxx WHERE 2708 <= id <= 1562755185;
2, select id from tbl_xxx WHERE id> = 2708 and id <= 1562755185;
3, select id from tbl_xxx WHERE id between 2708 and 1562755185;
```

I found that the performance is different, but I do not know why?

```
explain select id from  tblData  WHERE  id >=   2708 and id <= 1562755185    ORDER BY id asc  LIMIT 652000, 1000\G; 
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: tblData
         type: range
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 30461948
        Extra: Using where; Using index

explain select id from  tblData  WHERE  2708 <= id <= 1562755185    ORDER BY id asc  LIMIT 652000, 1000\G;         *************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: tblData
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 653000
        Extra: Using where; Using index
```

Comment: How did you measure performance and what were your results? The database will do some caching internally so if you run the same or similar queries back to back the second query will be at an advantage since it will probably hit the cache.

Comment: explain select id from  tblData  WHERE  id >=   2708 and id <= 1562755185    ORDER BY id asc  LIMIT 652000, 1000\G;
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: tblData
         type: range
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 30461948
        Extra: Using where; Using index

Comment: explain select id from  tblData  WHERE  2708 <= id <= 1562755185    ORDER BY id asc  LIMIT 652000, 1000\G;
          id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: tblData
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 653000
        Extra: Using where; Using index

Answer (score 2):

Queries **2** and **3** are equivalent so they should perform the same. Query **1** is something completely different; query **1** is equivalent to this:

```
select id from tbl_xxx WHERE (2708 <= id) <= 1562755185;
```

Since `2708 <= id` is a boolean expression and MySQL uses zero and one as booleans, your query is always comparing `1 <= 1562755185` or `0 <= 1562755185` and thus degenerates to this:

```
select id from tbl_xxx;
```

Assuming that `id` is never NULL of course.

So the queries are quite different and there's no reason to expect them to perform the same.

For example, I have a table kicking around that looks like this:

```
mysql> select * from stars;
+----+-------+
| id | stars |
+----+-------+
|  1 |     1 |
|  2 |     2 |
|  3 |     3 |
|  4 |     2 |
|  5 |     1 |
|  6 |     1 |
|  7 |     1 |
|  8 |     2 |
|  9 |     1 |
+----+-------+
```

A `between` does this:

```
mysql> select * from stars where id between 3 and 5;
+----+-------+
| id | stars |
+----+-------+
|  3 |     3 |
|  4 |     2 |
|  5 |     1 |
+----+-------+
```

But your `a <= id <= b` does this:

```
mysql> select * from stars where 3 <= id <= 5;
+----+-------+
| id | stars |
+----+-------+
|  1 |     1 |
|  2 |     2 |
|  3 |     3 |
|  4 |     2 |
|  5 |     1 |
|  6 |     1 |
|  7 |     1 |
|  8 |     2 |
|  9 |     1 |
+----+-------+
```